# Adding fragments to Back stack

Tags: android

I am trying to understand the working of back stack with Fragments
I am adding multiple fragments within a transaction

```
FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();

    ft.replace(R.id.lay,new fragment2());
    ft.replace(R.id.lay,new fragment3());

    ft.addToBackStack("multiple");

    ft.commit();
```

However when i popupbackstack with

```
fm.popBackStack("multiple",0);
```

nothing happens.
If i use the flag

```
FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE
```

things are working.
Kindly update why earlier is not working

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ***name*** argument from the [popBackStack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack(java.lang.String,%20int)) documentation:

(Emphasis mine)

> If non-null, this is the name of a previous back state to look for; if
>   found, **all states up to that state will be popped**. The
>   POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE flag can be used to control **whether the named
>   state itself is popped**. If null, only the top state is popped.

So basically *0* means remove all previous states **up to but except** the *"multiple"* transaction, while *POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE* means remove all previous states **up to and including** the *"multiple"* one.